# Can't integrate realm into android library module with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

My top level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'


buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        //region realm
        maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
        //endregion
    }
    dependencies {
        //region google()
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        //endregion
        //region jcenter()
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        //endregion
        //region maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        //to check fabric gradle ver
        //https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        //endregion
        //region realm
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.8.0"
        //endregion
    }
}
```

Here is my library module build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVer}"

    implementation "io.reactivex:rxjava:${rxJavaVersion}"
    implementation("io.reactivex:rxandroid:${rxAndroidVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'io.reactivex', module: 'rxjava'
    }

    implementation("com.github.davidmoten:rxjava-extras:${rxExtrasVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'io.reactivex', module: 'rxjava'
    }

    implementation('io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'io.reactivex', module: 'rxjava'
    }

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${daggerVersion}") {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-fragment'
    }
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${daggerVersion}"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${daggerVersion}"
    implementation "javax.inject:javax.inject:${javaxInjectVersion}"
    implementation "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:${javaxAnnotationVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVer}"

    ...
}
```

In result I can't make **Sync**, error is:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':module@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':module:debugCompileClasspath'.
Show Details
Affected Modules: module
```

But if I remote

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

then all works fine

Found issue: it was because of I have `failOnVersionConflict()` at top build gradle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the issue:
top **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()

        //region realm
        maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/realm/maven' }
        //endregion
    }
    dependencies {
        //region google()
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        //endregion
        //region jcenter()
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        //endregion

        //region realm
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.11.0"
        //endregion
    }
}

allprojects {
   ...

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jre7'

        resolutionStrategy {
            // fail eagerly on version conflict (includes transitive dependencies)
            // e.g. multiple different versions of the same dependency (group and name are equal)
            failOnVersionConflict()

            //this is needed:
            force "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version",
                    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:$kotlin_version",
                    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version",

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your root `build.gradle` to

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.11.0-SNAPSHOT"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
        }
    }
}
```

and it should work just fine (it does sync on my sample project). Note the `allprojects` block that you forgot. Also, you should `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` last.

Comment: Updated to 5.11.0 , but the issue still exist

Comment: Found issues  I have  `failOnVersionConflict()` at top build gradle

Comment: @NickUnuchek did you manage to fix it? also, do not forget to `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` last in your module `build.gradle`

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using `Realm` with `Kotlin`. Here are my `gradle` files.

It seems like the order of `Kotlin-kapt` and `kotlin-android-extensions` in the app `gradle` should be switched around. Check below

App `gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
// Add dependency
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0-alpha02'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Root level `gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    ext.lifecycle_version = '2.0.0'
    ext.anko_version='0.10.8'
    repositories {

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        // Add dependency
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.10.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Found issues I have failOnVersionConflict() at top build gradle